# How do I replace my double quotation marks with single ones around the title in the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using overleaf and biblatex.

At the moment I'm getting this:

Fithian, D. C. et al. (2004) “Epidemiology and natural history of acute patellar dislocation”. The American journal of sports medicine 32.5, pp. 1114–1121.

but want this:

Fithian, D. C. et al. (2004) 'Epidemiology and natural history of acute patellar dislocation'. The American journal of sports medicine 32.5, pp. 1114–1121.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Without more detail about how you are producing your bibliography, it's hard to tell. Are you using the basic `authoryear` style?

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to load the `csquotes` package with the `[style=british]` option.

Comment: I've added that as an answer. For your future questions, it's really helpful to add a minimal compilable document that shows the issue you're having.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the simplest way to do this is to load the `csquotes` package with the `[style=british]` option, which implements the British single quotation mark style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\textcite{aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]